# Can I tell where's the undefined reference to `vtable?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, undefined-reference, virtual-functions

I have a C++ class that I use to try to imitate C#'s interface, like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
  virtual void baa();
}
```

This is from a large Qt C++ project that compiles fine on *release*, but I got this error when I compile in *debug* mode:

> undefined reference to vtable

I know what that error means: a virtual method wasn't defined, right? My question is:

It only happen when in debug, and I don't know why. Can I find the source (i.e, the class) in which I haven't defined that method?

I'm willing to use Qt itself, a compiler option, an external tool, or anything else.

Comment: Which compiler are you using, and could you post the compiler commands you used for Debug and Release?

Comment: Usually this means that you declared a `virtual` function but did not provide a body. All virtual functions must have bodies, except for pure virtual ones.  Even if they are not called.

Comment: @M.M, though it's good to have bodies for all the `virtual` methods, to be precise, only those method bodies are required whose containing class's objects are being instantiated. For example, if I have `class B` and its derived `class D`. If I don't create any object of `B` and invoke `virtual void f();` then I can still live with that undefined `virtual` method. BTW, in case of pure `virtual` method, even though the body is not mandatory, one can still define it outside the class body.

Comment: @iammilind instanting `D` instantiates `B`.

Comment: @M.M, instantiating `B` via `D` or even explicitly, is still OK. However, there should not be a situation, where you end up passing this object and calling the `virtual f()` via `B&` or `B*` or `B`. Only in that case the linker error pops up. See in this [demo](http://ideone.com/kaG2LT), I have tried to cover few cases.

Comment: @iammilind see [basic.def.odr]/3 "A virtual member function is odr-used
if it is not pure", there's nothing about it having to occur in a potentially-evaluated expression (i.e. possibly be called), nor anything about any instantiation of an associated class

Answer (score 1):

> *"Can I find the source (i.e, the class) in which I haven't defined that method"*

For me the first suspect would be the `class Foo` itself. Check if it contains the definition of `void baa()` in it or not. If `Foo::baa()` is not defined, then you cannot do something like below:

```
Foo foo;
foo.baa();  // undefined reference for `Foo::baa()`
```

Now if you have indeed defined `Foo::baa()`, then possibly this error is coming for some other subclass of `Foo` (however I notice that g++ mentions which subclass, it's strange why it's not visible to you);

```
class Foo1 : public Foo
```

One easy way is to temporarily make the `Foo::baa` as **pure `virtual`**.

```
class Foo {
public: virtual void baa () = 0;
};
```

In such case, whichever subclass is not overriding this method, will generate the compiler error. This will make your finding easier due to line number etc.

Why it gives linker error in DEBUG mode is quite subjective and requires more info.